# How to map Stored Procedure with Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to retrieve the value of an SQL Sequence from a stored procedure using EF Code First with Fluent API mapping.

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Security].[GetHashSaltSequence]
AS

DECLARE @Sequence AS INT = NULL;
SELECT @Sequence = NEXT VALUE FOR SequenceName;

RETURN @Sequence;
```

How can I map this procedure in my DbContext using fluent API?

PS: Without using T-SQL such as

```
dbContext.MyEntity.SqlQuery("dbo.StoredProcedureName @myParam", myParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is another way to do it. Only a thing you can do is CURD operation mapping.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
{  
modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeMaster>()  
        .MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Insert(u => u.HasName("InsertEmployee", "dbo"))  
                                        .Update(u => u.HasName("UpdateEmployee", "dbo"))  
                                        .Delete(u => u.HasName("DeleteEmployee", "dbo"))  
        );  
}
```

Check the following links, hope this will be helpful for you

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/code-first-stored-procedure-entity-framework-6-0/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have EF do all the heavy lifting and assignments, then @Haider-m-rizvi is correct on code mapping.

But if all you want to do is just simply call a sproc in the database, then there is a much simpler approach to execution, using Fluent API.

Here are 3 general signatures all my SProcs/Function methods consist of.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteSProc<T> ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para ).ToArray();
    }
    public static T ExecuteSProcSingle<T> ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.SqlQuery<T>( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para ).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public static int ExecuteSProc ( this DbContext ctx , string schema , string sproc , params SqlParameter[] para ) {
        return ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( "Execute " + schema + "." + sproc , para );
    }
```

I will periodically post little quirks that I culminated over several posts into a singularly built concept of implementation here: http://theithobbit.blogspot.com/

The ultimate end-game with this design is to execute the SProc needed as if you were in SSMS, with Parameters, Schemas, etc defined as well.  Similar to executing RAW Dynamic SQL.